# How to get element inside iframe angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, iframe

Can't get DOM tree that loads iframe via src. Doesn't work through `ViewChild` and `getElementById`. Tell me how to get the DOM tree of everything that is inside the iframe?

```
<div class="card-iframe">
 <iframe #iframe class="iframe" id="iframes" src=""></iframe>
</div>

@Component({
  selector: 'kiosk-doctor-purposes-page',
  templateUrl: './doctor-purposes-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./doctor-purposes-page.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DoctorPurposesPageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('iframe', { static: true }) public iframe: ElementRef<HTMLIFrameElement>;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(window.parent.document.getElementById('iframes'));
    const iframe: any = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframes');
    // iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('div').innerText = 'asfdsdf3rsdf';
  }
```

```
@ViewChild('iframe', { static: true }) public iframe: ElementRef<HTMLIFrameElement>;
```

and

```
const iframe: any = window.parent.document.getElementById('iframes');
```

don't work.